# Show auth token on Swashbuckle UI

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, swashbuckle

I've protected ASP NET Core WEB API 2.1 through IS4 (implicit flow). And now I need to document my API. I've decided to use swashbuckle and configured security here.

Thus, I have swashbuckle UI that can login user. As result of the login swashbuckle get authorization token and stores it somewhere internally (I wasn't able to find it in cookie or session etc.).

When I make request swashbuckle ui automatically attached this token to request (Authorization: Bearer tokenvalue), but I need to show the token somewhere on UI after user login. I'd like to give user possibility to enter token manually to each request instead of magic performed by swashbuckle.

So, is there a way to show the token on UI along with each endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

The swashbuckle UI is a separate project ([Swagger-UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)) 
and you should see everything that is sent to the server in the curl section:
[image]

You also mentioned:

> I'd like to give user possibility to enter token manually

There is no such an option, but you can put a request on the project, see what they have to say.

Comment: Thank you! I've decided to expose endpoint where user can enter his credentials and get back a token value. And also, I've added IOperationFilter, that adds required NonBodyParameter to each action method, that marked with [Authorization] attribute. This actions satisfy my requirements :-)